# For Redshift DB, Hibernate expects Long but finds BigInteger

Tags: java, hibernate, amazon-redshift

I have a class for Hibernate:

```
@lombok.Data
public class RedshiftRecord {

    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;
}
```

The corresponding type for this column in Redshift/postgres is BIGINT, here is the SQL source:

```
CREATE TABLE SAMPLE
(
    id bigint distkey sortkey
);
```

BIGINT is a signed eight-byte integer. However, when I try to run this code:

```
SQLQuery query = getSession().createSQLQuery("SELECT id FROM sample LIMIT 1");
query.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(RedshiftRecord.class));
RedshiftRecord record = (RedshiftRecord) query.uniqueResult();
```

I get this error

```
org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor: IllegalArgumentException in class: com.org.model.RedshiftRecord, setter method of property: id
    org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor: expected type: java.lang.Long, actual value: java.math.BigInteger
```

If I change id like so:

```
private BigInteger id;
```

then it works fine. Is there a way to make Hibernate do the conversion from a Redshift/postgres BIGINT to a Java Long? The definition of BIGINT seems closer to a Java Long than a Java BigIntger

I would prefer not to use BigIntegers to save on runtime/space.

Comment: What is the concrete problem you're facing in the first place? Post the code and the exception stack trace.

Comment: I added the error message and explained  the problem better.

Comment: @JBNizet do you have any ideas?

Comment: Nope. But you still didn't post the relevant code: entity + code causing the exception.

Comment: @JBNizet I think I've added what you wanted.

Comment: Don't use a SQL query. By using a SQL query, Hibernate has no idea that you're selecting from an entity whose ID field is mapped to a Long. It just knows it gets a BIGINT back, and applies the default mapping consisting in transforming it to a BigInteger. Map your table to an entity, and use a JPQL query: `select sample.id from Sample sample`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@JBNizet pointed me in the right direction, but I was able to get it to work with a SQL Query. Effectively, I followed the guide here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_annotations.htm

I used the @Entity Annotation on my model class and replaced

```
    query.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(RedshiftRecord.class));
```

with

```
 query.addEntity(RedshiftRecord.class);
```

This allowed me to automatically cast the BIGINTS to Longs.